# How dynamically handle self-type annotation in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, self-type

I am trying to use the cake pattern here for my project. Which is working fine.

Here is a pseudo code for that.

```
trait Source {
  def dataset: String
}

trait FileSource extends Source{
  def path: String
  override def dataset: String = // Something here
}

trait DBSource extends Source{
  def ip: String
  override def dataset: String = // Something here
}

trait Processor {
  self: Source =>
  val name: String
  def output: String = transform(self.dataset)
  def transform: (String => String)
}

trait FilterWhilteSpace extends Processor {
  self: Source =>
  override val name: String = "filter_whitespaces"
  override def transform: (String => String) = _.replaceAll("\w", "")
}

trait MaskPassword extends Processor {
  self: Source =>
  override val name: String = "mask_password"
  override def transform: (String => String) = // Something here
}

class FilterWhilteSpaceForFile extends FilterWhilteSpace with FileSource {
  override def path: String = "abcd"
}

class FilterWhilteSpaceForDB extends FilterWhilteSpace with DBSource {
  override def ip: String = "localhost"
}

class MaskPasswordForDB extends FilterWhilteSpace with DBSource {
  override def ip: String = "localhost"
}
```

So the problem is here, Data from local DBSource is getting read twice (Once in `FilterWhilteSpaceForDB` and second in `MaskPasswordForDB`). Can we create an instance of `LocalDBSource` which can be used in both or resolve my `Source` self-type annotation dependency?

```
class LocalDBSource extends DBSource {
  override def ip: String = "localhost"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your design has `Processor` inherit from `Source` which means that each instance of `Processor` has it's own `Source` instance. You need to separate the `Source` hierarchy from the `Processor` hierarchy:

```
trait Source {
  def dataset: String
}

case class FileSource(path: String) extends Source {
  def dataset: String = ???
}

case class DBSource(ip: String) extends Source {
  def dataset: String = ???
}

trait Processor {
  def source: Source  
  val name: String  
  def output: String = transform(source.dataset)  
  def transform: String => String
}

case class FilterWhilteSpace(source: Source) extends Processor {
  val name: String = "filter_whitespaces"
  def transform: String => String = _.replaceAll("\\w", "")
}

case class MaskPassword(source: Source) extends Processor {
  val name: String = "mask_password"
  def transform: String => String = ???
}

val db = DBSource("localhost")
val a = FilterWhilteSpace(db)
val b = MaskPassword(db)
```

Also note that implementing an abstract method is not overriding, so you don't need the `override` keyword. Only use `override` when you are replacing an existing concrete implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this will work, but it's hard to apply these changes in the project. Looking some kind of hack so it can work with both ways.

Comment: Having `Processor` inherit from `Source` is a broken design so I strongly suggest that you fix it. If you want a hack then you need to make that clear in the question rather than focussing on the self-type annotation which isn't relevant to the problem.